# Slow GCC compilation on codeblocks

Tags: gcc, compilation, codeblocks

I always used codeblocks to program in C, now that I have a more powerful computer processing and memory, it's taking like 3~4 seconds to compile and show in the screen a simple console application written
 *Hello World!*.

Anyone have any idea why is that and how to fix it then go back to normal ? Thanks !

Comment: Is GCC fast when you compile from cmd; gcc -o my.exe my.c ? try to turn of antivirus?

Comment: Can't do that command on windows ;s

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it is caused by your Anti-Virus.
Try going to your anti-virus settings and find "exclusions" or something similar.
Then exclude CodeBlocks, turn off any scanning or checking for it.

I use Kaspersky Anti-virus and I had to exlude CodeBlocks, gcc.exe and g++.exe (in the MinGW\bin folder).
The compile time went from 6-7 seconds to almost instant.
Hope that helped!